# tmux conf file not being picked up in Mac

Tags: macos, tmux

I have a ~/.tmux_conf file on my Mac (El Capitan). However it is not getting picked up. For e.g. I have changed the default binding from C-b to C-q and that's not working. This same file works fine on my Linux machine. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is it supposed to be put in another location?

Thanks
Neha.

Comment: Is it really called `~/.tmux_conf`? The tmux man page says it should `~/.tmux.conf`. Notice the dot.

Comment: Doh! That's right. I made an error when copying the file. Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of `~/.tmux_conf` to `~/.tmux.conf`. That should do it.